# How to add / run the validators for complex type data properties in breeze schema

Tags: validation, breeze, complextype

I am trying to do the validation for the data properties present in complex type,if I add the validators as like the normal data property,it is not running the validations. Below shown is the sample breeze schema and the complex type used.

Breeze Schema:

```
        {
            "name": "mailingAddress",
            "complexTypeName": "Address:#test"
        }
```

Complex Type:(Address.json)

```
        {
            "name": "address",
            "dataType": "String",
            "validators": [
                {
                    "name": "required"
                }
            ]
        }
```

The required Validator is not running during the page load. Also, the predefined /custom validators are not triggering when the data property changes.

Is there any specific way to do the validations for complex type (Single and array of objects)?

Kindly help out to do the validation for complex types.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the 'required' validator probably did run.  The problem is that scalar complex types are never null; they may contain all null values, but the complex instance itself always exists. So the 'required' validator, which simply asks if the property is null, will never fail.  Similarly for arrays of complexTypes the array will always exist but it may be empty ( as opposed to null).

So you will need to create a complex validator for your instance that checks if all of the values within the complexType are null.

For arrays of complexTypes you will need to check that the array is empty.

Hope this makes sense.